# How would you check to see if a user selected one radio option over the other using PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

How would you check to see if a user selected one radio option over the other using PHP?

I'm a newbie when it comes to PHP and i've been trying to work with a radio button group where if a user selects **Yes** the form will relay a success message but if a user selects **No** a user will be redirected to an error page.

Code below:

**PHP**

```
//check to see if the child is not enrolled in school
//If the value of enrolled is No
if (isset($_POST["enrolled"]) ) {
  //redirects user to an error page.
  header("Location: /form-error.shtm");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      <span>I am currently enrolled in high-school</span> 
    </legend>
    <div>
      <span>
        <input id="Yes" name="enrolled" type="radio" value="Yes" />
        <label>Yes</label>
      </span>
      <span>
        <input id="No" name="enrolled" type="radio" value="No" />
        <label>No</label>
      </span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your <form ...> tag?

Comment: vansihed, lol. I took the snippet out from the form but it'll help I can add it it to the form.

Comment: Well one issue is that you're checking for `$_POST["enrollment"]` but your radio buttons are named `enrolled`.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks I noticed that too after I posted the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that on the PHP page, you are using a condition to see if `$_POST["enrollment"]` is set, but then you're not checking the value of the variable.

You should do this :

```
if (isset($_POST["enrollment"]) ) {
    if($_POST["enrollment"]==="Yes"){
         //success message
    }
    else{
      //redirects user to an error page.
      header("Location: /form-error.shtm");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_POST['enrolled'] == 'No'){
header("Location: /form-error.shtm");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Yes and No are the only two options you are working with, simply assign both radio buttons a value, and evaluate that value on back-end:

`<input type="radio" name="rad" value="y" />Yes 
<input type="radio" name="rad" value="n" />No`
 On server side, simply use $_POST['rad'] to check the value.